# how to get or display duplicate data in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Can somebody share some code how to get or display duplicate data from my database using codeigniter.

```
[id]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[3]
[4]
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean how to show which rows have duplicates in a db table?

Comment: I believe that column id is not auto-increment. Need more info...

Comment: I just assumed that i have that data and number 3 is duplicate. so the output must show 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name  GROUP BY column_name HAVING COUNT(column_name) > 1;
```

You can do like this in codeigniter

```
$sql_select = 'SELECT column_name FROM table_name  GROUP BY column_name HAVING COUNT(column_name) > 1';
$query = $this->db->query($this->sql_select);
$result = $query->result_array();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. anyway how to do this in codeigniter model?

Comment: @Dennis, Paste you code what you have tried, It will be clear your requirement.

Comment: $this->db->having('id>1');  I don't know if this is right.

Comment: @Dennis, I have changed my answer, Check it, If it works mark the answer as useful.